# Approximation of a function as it goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, approximation

For $0< H <1$. How does

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}[(n+1)^{2H} + (n-1)^{2H}-2n^{2H}] &\approx H(2H-1)n^{2H-2} \\
& \to 0, \quad n \to \infty
\end{align}

I don't understand why does the left-hand side of the equation can be approximated by the right-hand side of the equation...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind professors work here... Imagine asking your professor the same. Be polite. In my opinion, 'thanksssss' is inappropriate. 

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya alright thanks for the edit!

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's literally the only line and I thought of the same too "where is the rest of the proof".

Comment: @YvesDaoust my bad my bad. Thanks for the answer! Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

By the binomial theorem,

$$(n\pm1)^a=n^a\pm an^{a-1}+\frac{a(a-1)}2n^{a-2}\pm\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)}{3!}n^{a-3}+\cdots$$

Apply it and simplify.